# How to set puma to start on server start/reboot with capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3, puma

I was going through [puma upstart script](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart) and I tried to set it up on my server. But, after some trial and error I realized that I shouldn't be  doing this manually and my deployment script i.e. **capistrano should be doing this for me.**

I google this but I could not much other than 2 lines on [capistrano-puma](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma#usage):

> For Jungle tasks (beta), these options exist:
>
> ```
> set :puma_jungle_conf, '/etc/puma.conf'
> set :puma_run_path, '/usr/local/bin/run-puma'
> ```

I am not sure how to use this and make capistrano do this rather than me manually doing it.

*Work done so far:*

I followed this blog- [Deploying a Rails App on Ubuntu 14.04 with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) and it works like a charm, **except** that I have to remember to run `cap production puma:restart` if I restart the server (or the puma process dies and I get cloudwatch alarms).

Following the [official docs](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart), I made a config file `/etc/puma.conf`:

```
/home/deploy/apps/<app_name>/current
```

but it is unable to find `puma.rb`- Naturally, as `puma.rb` is in

```
<app_name>/shared/puma.rb
```

and not in

```
<app_name>/current/config/puma.rb
```

The actual error I get in the logs:

```
/home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/dsl.rb:26:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/dsl.rb:26:in `_load_from'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/dsl.rb:9:in `load'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:204:in `block in load'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:201:in `each'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:201:in `load'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:62:in `initialize'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:65:in `new'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:65:in `initialize'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/bin/puma:8:in `new'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/bin/puma:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    from /home/deploy/apps/voggle/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I think I have a similar proble,. Im trying to solve by uploading puma.conf to see if the configuration in that file will be considered as it should.

Comment: Once I get it going ill post my answer here.